# Difficulty understanding a financial question

Tags: calculus, finance

> To have $\$50,000$ for college tuition in $20$ years, what gift $y_o$ should a grandparent make now? Assume $c = 10\%$. What continuous deposit should a parent make during $20$ years? If the parent saves $s = \$1000$ per year, when does he or she reach $\$50,000$ and retire?

I think the gift a grandparent should make is $y_0=50000e^{-0.1\cdot20}=50000/e^2\approx6766.76$ dollars. But then I do not understand the continuous deposit that a parent should make. Is the grandparent's gift not enough to have $\$50,000$ in $20$ years?

Comment: The grandparent's gift and the parent's savings are for separate purposes.  There are three different questions here.  The second does not specify the desired outcome, so you don't have enough information to answer it.  You have the first done, the grandparent's gift.  The third is the parent's retirement.

Comment: @RossMillikan For the third question, assuming $y_0=0$, we have $50000=\frac{1000}{0.1}(e^{0.1t}-1)$, which gives $t=10\ln 6\approx18$ years. So, why does it ask a question (the second one) that cannot be answered?

Comment: I believe the second question is asking you what a parent should continuously deposit during 20 years to save $\$50000$.

Answer (score 0):

1. $y_0$ is the present value of $y=\$\, 50,000$, that is
   $$
   y_0=y\,\mathrm e^{-ct}=50,000 \times \mathrm e^{-0.1 \times 20}\approx \$\, 6,766.76
   $$
2. starting with $y_0=0$ the continuous deposit $s$ to obtain $y$ in $t=20$ years is found by
   $$
   y=\frac{s}{c}\left(e^{ct}-1\right)
   $$
   that is 
   $$
   s=\frac{yc}{e^{ct}-1}=\frac{50,000\times 0.1}{e^{0.1\times 20}-1}=\frac{5,000}{e^{2}-1}\approx \$\, 782.59
   $$
3. with a continuous deposit $s=\$\,1,000$ we have
   $$
   y=\frac{s}{c}\left(e^{ct}-1\right)\quad\Longrightarrow\quad  t=\frac{1}{c}\log\left(\frac{yc}{s}+1\right)
   $$
   that is 
   $$
   t=\frac{1}{0.1}\log\left(\frac{5000}{1000}+1\right)=10\log 6\approx 18 \text{ years}
   $$